# laravel 5 return a variable from blade view

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I generate a list of databases the user has. Behind every database I put a delete icon that should call a function that deletes the database.

with this code I make the view

> return view('site.database')->with('info', $info);

inside the view I use a foreachloop to show all the databases

```
@foreach($info['list'] as $database)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$database}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{URL::route('dbDelete')}}">
            <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/753/gnome_desktop/24/gnome_edit_delete.png"></a></td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

the route 'dbDelete' calls on a function that deletes the database, but this function needs to know wich database to delete so it needs the parameter $database. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the route like this:

```
Route::get('delete/{db}', [
    'as' => 'dbDelete', 
    'uses' => 'DbController@delete'
]);
```

Then, you pass the name like:

```
<td><a href="{{ route('dbDelete', ['db' => $database])}}">
```